# Performance One Hot Encoding

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, encoding, data-science

I have a big dataset (10gb) and I have to perform One Hot Encoding (OHE). In the data preparation the OHE is the bottle neck, it is taking too much time.

I am using this library to do it: [category encoders](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/onehot.html)

```py
from category_encoders.one_hot import OneHotEncoder

OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df)
```

For a small sample of the dataframe is already taking too long.

How can I speed up the process? Maybe parallelize it? Another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a costumed function or the same function and run it in parallel.
This can be done with multiprocessing library.
Assuming your function is 'My_Fun' that gets as input the number of entry and returns one hot encoding, you can run the following lines of code:

```
import multiprocessing
inputs = range(sample_size)
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print("number of available cores:", num_cores)
results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(My_Fun)(i) for i in inputs)
```